# How to recursively call a function that has a void function as a parameter in C?

Tags: c, function, recursion, terminal, code-snippets

I am a beginner in C and I wanted to use a void function that has a void function as a passed argument, and then I wanted to call it in a recursive way. For example `void inOrder (struct node *root, void (*f) (struct node *i))`
But apparently, I can't use it because the argument has no return type. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to call it recursively?
Thank you!

Comment: How are you trying to use this parameter?

Comment: This parameter will print the data of  (i->data) but I need to use this on every struct num that I have. So that's why I wanted to use it recursively

Comment: The only reason you would need a return type is to add a head case. What is the head or "stopping case" for your recursive algorithm?

Comment: My stopping case is if any of my values is null

Comment: Why can't you use `f`? Where is the recursion? What are you really trying to do? What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). ALso know that this question is really an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in its current form.

Comment: The thing is I want to traverse a tree in a recursive way and the ```f``` will print every value of the node. C won't let me write ```void inOrder (root->leftChild, (*f) (root->leftChild))``` because the f doesn't have a return type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown in a comment, `void inOrder (root->leftChild, (*f) (root->leftChild))` has two errors:

- `void` should not be present. When calling a function, we simply write its name followed by the arguments in parentheses. We do not declare its type.
- The expression `inOrder (root->leftChild, (*f) (root->leftChild))` attempts to call `f`. The second parameter of `inOrder` is a pointer to a function, so pass a pointer to a function, which is just `f`:

```
inOrder(root->leftChild, f)
```

Also note that you are not calling `f` recursively. `f` does not call `f`, directly or indirectly. `inOrder` may call itself, and hence it recurses, but it just calls `f` simply, not recursively.